# drupal : how to display the taxonomy term and node title at view block

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I've taxonomy terms as follow

```
term1
term2
term3
```

And I'll add 6 content by terms
I want to display a block as follow

```
term1
-content1
-content2
term2
-content3
-content4
term3
-content5
-content6
```

How Can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Drupal [`Views`](https://drupal.org/project/views) Module which can be reusable and option is View Block

Tutorial URL: http://www.webbykat.com/2012/02/creating-monthly-archive-block-drupal-7-views

Answer (score 0):

View is the solution.

1. You create a new content view
2. In format section, you select format : Grid and show : Fields
3. You add fields : tag (the name of your taxonomy) and node title
4. On Grid settings, You select tag field as the Grouping field Nr.1